# Is there a way to auto click a button in a program?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to run [Windows Enabler](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/Windows-Enabler.shtml) on startup, I can get the program loaded by putting it in the startup folder, but in order to activate it, it needs to be clicked on in the taskbar, is there some way to automate that?
It's the blue squares on the bottom. I'd like to have that click every time on startup, instead of me doing it manually.

[image: screenshot of windows enabler running]
[image: screenshot of windwos enabler active]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a screenshot illustrating what you want to click on? It’s probably doable with AutoHotKey or AutoIt or the like.

Comment: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm